# C++ Virtual Functions Question

Tags: c++, virtual

Hey, so if I have a Base class and 2 derived classes...

```
class Base
{
  virtual void Output()
  {
     cout << "OUTPUTTING A BASE OBJECT" << endl;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   void Ouput()
   {
     cout << "OUTPUTTING A DERIVED" << endl;
   }
};

class OtherDerived : public Base
{

};
```

As I understand it, if I try to call Output from OtherDerived, it would fail. Is there a way to override Output for some derived versions of Base but not others?

Comment: what are you exactly tryiing to do.show us ur main function

Comment: why do you think, it will not fail.

Answer (score 10):

Calling `Output` for objects of the `OtherDerived` class fails not because it's virtual, but because it's declared `private` in `Base` (well not explicitly - but `private` is the default in classes when nothing else is specified)

Change the declaration of `Base` to:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void Output()
  {
     cout << "OUTPUTTING A BASE OBJECT" << endl;
  }
};
```

And this will work. `protected` will also work. Since `Output` isn't *pure virtual*, it can be called from subclasses that don't override it.

Answer (score 0):

It would not fail - it would call Base::Output. What you want, ie. overriding "for some derived classes, but not others" *is* how inheritance works. You don't need to do anything further.